# Magento 'failed opening' migration file path error

Tags: php, magento

I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysq14.php'
for inclusion (include_path='/vhost/vhost15/p/a/r/mageecommerce.com/www/app/code/local:/vhost/vhost15/p/a/r/mageecommerce.com/www/app/code/community:/vhost/vhost15/p/a/r/mageecommerce.com/www/app/code/core:/vhost/vhost15/p/a/r/mageecommerce.com/www/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
in /vhost/vhost15/p/a/r/mageecommerce.com/www/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

I'm getting 500 Internal Server Error because of this.

How would I fix this?

Comment: check var/log files once.

Comment: The file Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php exists on a standard Magento 1.9.2.4 install, but your code seems to be looking for the wrong file - `Mysq14`, not `Mysql4`?

Answer (score 0):

To do successful migration, you need to follow below steps.

1. Update new secure and unsecure base_url in table **core_config_data**. (dont forget to put "**http://**" as prefix and "**/**" as postfix)
2. delete "**var**" folder. (If you afraid to do this just delete "**cache**" and "**session**" folder).
3. Hit Magento url in your favorite browser. Installation process will come up, just enter all your details and finish your setup.

If you have followed this steps already, then delete **var** folder and run again.